# Nextjs - Fast Refresh throws error on any page other than index

Tags: reactjs, next.js, refresh, headless-cms

I ran into a weird issue with my recent Nextjs build that I cannot figure out. Any page other than the index.js page throws an error saying that Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload whenever I make a change to the page.

Nextjs version: 12.2.3
React version: 17.0.2

The error in the terminal (no console errors):

```
Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/fast-refresh#how-it-works
Error: Aborted because ./pages/contact.js is not accepted
Update propagation: ./pages/contact.js -> ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-client-pages-loader.js?absolutePagePath=D%3A%5Csites%5Coverpeaks%5Coverpeaks-nextjs%5Cpages%5Ccontact.js&page=%2Fcontact!
    at applyHandler (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1669755499923:869:31)
    at http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1669755499923:552:21
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

contact.js:

```
const contact = () => {
  return <div>contact</div>;
};
export default contact;
```

next.config.js:

```
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */

module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    images: {
      allowFutureImage: true,
    },
  },
  images: {
    domains: ["cms.overpeaks.ca"],
  },
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve = {
      ...config.resolve,
      fallback: {
        fs: false,
        path: false,
        os: false,
      },
    };
    return config;
  },
};
```

What my structure looks like:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1zUl.png)

I noticed this while working on my about.js page, so I thought it might have to do with the code within there, so I created a brand new page (contact.js) and am having the same issue. I've tried removing everything within next.config.js with no difference. At this point I'm starting to think there's a bug within Nextjs causing this.